# Regex weird behavior, won't match what I need

Tags: c#, regex

I have three different inputs.

```
<inverse content="HelloWorlD"/>
<reverse content="helloworld"/>
<repeat value="2" content="helloworld"/>
```

In the first input, I need to inverse the chars in the string which is in the content.

On the second one, I need to do the same, but reverse them.

At the third one I need to repeat the string which is in the content X number times when X is the value number.

I am using Regex to match the input.

It matches everything perfectly.

[image]

It works perfectly for the inverse and the reverse command, but when I try to match the repeat line it puts them in two different matches which doesn't work for me.

[image]

```
string line = Console.ReadLine();
Regex pattern = new Regex("(\\w+) \\w+=\"(\\w+)\"| \\w+=\"(\\w+)\"");

List<string> list = new List<string>();

while (line != "stop")
{
    MatchCollection matcher = pattern.Matches(line);

    foreach (Match match in matcher)
    {
        string command = match.Groups[1].ToString();
        string content;
        int value;

        switch (command)
        {
            case "inverse":
                content = match.Groups[2].ToString();
                list.Add(InverseContent(content));
                break;
            case "reverse":
                content = match.Groups[2].ToString();
                list.Add(ReverseContent(content));
                break;
            case "repeat":
                value = int.Parse(match.Groups[2].ToString());
                content = match.Groups[3].Value;
                for (int i = 0; i < value; i++)
                {
                    list.Add(content);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    line = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me for some reason. http://prntscr.com/b2l4hn

Comment: Using `@` means that you will not have to have the double \\, but it will not prevent you from needing to escape the quotes.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the second value optional with `?`:

```
"(\\w+) \\w+=\"(\\w+)\"(\\s+\\w+=\"(\\w+)\")?"
```

For the "repeat" case it will yield the values in group #2 and #4.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but can you explain me why it wasn't working with mine pattern ? Isn't the | sign the same ?

Comment: The `|` sign stands for alternatives. It means OR. So it matches the left expression OR the right expression, not both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

try this regex :

(\w+) \w+="(\d+){0,1}" \w+="(\w+)"

Answer (score 0):

This may be overkill, but I'm going to post it anyway.

Since your data appears to be well formed XML - we can use an XML parser to get a structured list of commands. This will make your solution easier to test and able to handle more complex situations. It will handle situations where the input is formed like `<inverse content="HelloWorld"></inverse>` as well as reordering the attributes `<repeat content="x" value="3" />` instead of `<repeat value="3" content="x" />`. It can also support any random input inside the value (not just word characters).

If your input is surrounded by a root element (which you could insert yourself if you don't get it that way) - the input is well-formed xml. Example:

```
//file: input.xml
<input>
  <inverse content="HelloWorld" />
  <reverse content="helloworld" />
  <repeat value="2" content="helloworld" />
</input>
```

We could then construct a class to represent your list of input commands as follows:

```
[XmlRoot("input")] //indicate that this class represents the xml file
public class CommandList
{   
    // tell the XmlSerializer which <element> belongs to which class.
    [XmlElement("repeat", typeof(Repeat))]
    [XmlElement("reverse", typeof(Reverse))]
    [XmlElement("inverse", typeof(Inverse))]
    public List<Command> Commands { get; } = new List<Command>();
}
```

The `Command` class is [abstract](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5.aspx), and has three different implementations, depending on the element:

```
public abstract class Command
{
    [XmlAttribute("content")]
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public abstract void Process(List<string> output);
}
```

After defining the abstract class, we can create the different commands as separate classes:

```
public class Inverse : Command
{
    public override void Process(List<string> output)
    {
        var inverseContent = this.Content; //todo: process
        output.Add(inverseContent);
    }
}
public class Reverse : Command
{
    public override void Process(List<string> output)
    {
        var reverseContent = this.Content; //todo: process
        output.Add(reverseContent);
    }
}
```

For the `Repeat` class, there is one extra attribute, the `value`.

```
public class Repeat : Command
{
    [XmlAttribute("value")]
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public override void Process(List<string> output)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.Value; i++)
        {
            output.Add(this.Content);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, to run your solution:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CommandList));
var result = (CommandList)serializer.Deserialize(File.OpenRead("input.xml"));
var output = new List<string>();
foreach (var command in result.Commands)
{
    command.Process(output);
}
```

Comment: That's an overkill indeed, but anyways thanks for the time and effort. It's an interesting solution, I am happy to see a different approach to solving the problem. Thanks, again.